# Service not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read a JSON file and post its data on a site. I should tell you that I'm new to angular so I don't really know whats going on in my app.js
The error i got is:

```
ReferenceError: MyService is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:20)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at T.instance (angular.min.js:86)
    ...
```

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
app.service("MyService", function($http, $q)
{    
    var defferd = $q.defer();   
    $http.get('JSON/nosaints.json').then(function(data){
        defferd.resolve(data);
    });

    this.GetPlayers = function()
    {
        return defferd.promise;
    }

}).controller("MyController", function($scope){

    var promise = MyService.GetPlayers();       
    promise.then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.team = data;
        console.log($scope.team);
    });   
})
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div class="inner cover" ng-controller="MyController">
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="player in team">
          //print from player here
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Put MyService into your controller.  `controller("MyController", function($scope, MyService){`

Comment: @KKKKKKKK Doing that gives me this `TypeError: $q.deffer is not a function`

Comment: The error is pretty clear:  You mispelled `defer`.  It should be this `var deferred = $q.defer();`

Comment: @KKKKKKKK And that solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Services are *injectable* dependencies. You need to inject them where you want to use them (i.e. in *controllers*, *directives*, other services...):

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, MyService){

    var promise = MyService.GetPlayers();       
    promise.then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.team = data;
        console.log($scope.team);
    });   
});
```

BTW, you should use [*strict dependency injection*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) if you want to later minify your code:

```
var controllerFunc = function($scope, MyService){

    var promise = MyService.GetPlayers();       
    promise.then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.team = data;
        console.log($scope.team);
    });   
};
controllerFunc.$inject = ["$scope", "MyService"];

app.controller("MyController", controllerFunc);
```